Trino: Receiving an Unfamiliar ID Instead of Username with OAuth2 Azure EntraID Authentication
I'm working on configuring Azure Entra ID with Trino for authentication. Although the setup appears to be successful, I'm encountering an issue where a strange ID is being displayed in the Trino UI instead of my Azure ID.

I'm unsure where this ID originates from. I've verified that it isn't the object ID of the AAD user. Since I'm using Azure ID in file-based access control, I need to identify this ID to map it with the corresponding Azure ID.
Below is my config.properties
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=80
discovery.uri=http://localhost:80
http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=443
http-server.https.keystore.path=/etc/trino/healthrxcert.pem
http-server.authentication.type=oauth2,PASSWORD
password-authenticator.config-files=/etc/trino/password-authenticator.properties
http-server.authentication.oauth2.issuer=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenent ID>/v2.0
http-server.authentication.oauth2.client-id=<ID>
http-server.authentication.oauth2.client-secret=<SECRET>
http-server.authentication.oauth2.auth-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenent ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
http-server.authentication.oauth2.token-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenent ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
http-server.authentication.oauth2.jwks-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenent ID>/discovery/v2.0/keys
http-server.authentication.oauth2.userinfo-url=https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
http-server.authentication.oauth2.scopes=openid
web-ui.authentication.type=oauth2


Are you still looking for the solution?

yes Pratik we are still struggling with this.
